How to fix erased On-Board Usb-Blaster FPGA (MAX II EPM240T100C3 on board Terasic DE10-Lite)
I have Terasic DE10-Lite board (with Altera MAX10 fpga), which use Altera Max II EPM240T100C3N (and usb-b + ftdi chip) for on-board usb-blaster logic. After explore 8 pins jtag holes on the board, i flash via that jtag and external usb-blaster cable ( to MAX II fpga ) stock hello world.
Previously i read (Examine) original MAX II bitstream to file (according to Messages there wasnt errors and file was save succefully). After understand that on-board usb-blaster stop work, and Max II used for it, i try recover Max II and flash original bitstream file (operation ends successfully) but on-board usb-blaster still dont work.
I explore all forums and github but didnt find any on-board usb-blaster bitstreams or HDL sources of usb-blaster to try flash. So what can i do now ? Ask someone with same board to dump MAX II bitstream and share to me?

